# How do I just move the nose in, not squash it?

Tags: modeling

I don't know how to delete my last question, so I'm just making a new one.

I'm making a mouth and nose. All I want to do is move the nose in a bit, but this happens:

[image]

[image]

How do I not deform the nose (under the mirror modifier) while moving it in?

Comment: What do you mean by move it in? Move it in on the face or shrink its width?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Clipping in Mirror modifier. This will prevent vertices from cliping in the middle. After editing the nose, enable it back, cause it ensures middle vertices to be joined after applying the modifier.